# How to reverse a list using slicing?

Tags: python, string, list

Let's suppose I have a string text = "Hello".
I want to print separately the odd/even positions of the string. I have managed to do this in normal order (see code below).

The problem now is that I want to do the same but starting from the end. That is, odd now equals to "le" and even equals to "olH".

```
    text = "Hello"

    # Normal order
    odd = text[1::2] # --> "el"
    even = text[0::2] # --> "Hlo"

    # Reverse order (WRONG)
    odd = text[-2::2] 
    even = text[-1::2]
```

Answer (score 5):

You also need to negate the increment:

```
oddReverse = text[-2::-2]
evenReverse = text[-1::-2]
```